# Allowing user to print specific pages in C# WPF FlowDocument Application

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, flowdocument

[image: WPF print box with disabled print rages]

The box above is what is called when a print() method is initiated on a flowDocumentPageViewer of flowDocumentScrollViewer.

In My application, I want my users to be able to select specific page range to print but the options seems to be disabled in the printbox. is there a way I can activate this in code.

Help will be appreciated as this tied to to a project I am doing.

Answer (score 3):

After alot of surfing the internet with no answer, I decided to check out my Library, my best pick was pro WPF 4.5 in c# 4th edition and I got the answer on page 941 chapter 29. Actually  have read this before but I did not pick to detail and the author stressed that calling `PrintDialog.UserPageRangeEnabled` and others should be done before calling `PrintDialog.ShowDialog()`

I fixed this with that and viola, after months of stress, I got it right.

Although most of the printing features like `PrintDialog.currentPageEnabled` and `PrintDialog.SelectedPagesEnabled` are supported only in .NET 4.5 but I'm ok with with the `PrintDialog.UserPageRangeEnabled` because my app targets .NET 4 CF for I want it to be available to window xp users.

Below is the box now.

[image: Printing with PrintDialog.UserPageRangeEnabled]

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the following post which explains printing from a `FlowDocument`:

[Printing a WPF FlowDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345009/printing-a-wpf-flowdocument)

You can find out more from 'Mitesh Sureja's Blog':

[Printing Flow Document using WPF PrintDialog](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/printing-flow-document-using-wpf.html)

Comment: All this I know but the issue here is, I want to user to select page rage from the box, but it is disabled. I tried to set the UserPageRangeEnabled property to try but still, the page range options are still not active. All I want is the user to be able to specify a page range before printing.